# Finding out if the mail was sent successfully or not in EWS Java API

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

I am using Java EWS API to send a mail using SendandSaveCopy. I want to put a checker if the mail was sent successfully or not (in case the internet was not working). When I try to do that, it shows that it is a void method. is there any way to find out whether the mail was sent successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `EmailMessage` class, use method `setIsDeliveryReceiptRequested`and set to `true` before you send the mail. 
Once the mail is sent and the messaging server has delivered the mail to recipient, you will receive a message (if supported by the messaging server) reporting when the recipient has received the message.

```
   /**
   * Sets the checks if is delivery receipt requested.
   *
   * @param value the new checks if is delivery receipt requested
   * @throws Exception the exception
   */
  public void setIsDeliveryReceiptRequested(Boolean value) throws Exception {
    this.getPropertyBag().setObjectFromPropertyDefinition(
        EmailMessageSchema.IsDeliveryReceiptRequested, value);
  }
```

https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/blob/master/src/main/java/microsoft/exchange/webservices/data/core/service/item/EmailMessage.java#L437

DOC from official API

> The Message object contains two properties that can direct the underlying MAPI system to report successful receipt of the message: DeliveryReceipt and ReadReceipt.
>   When you set these properties to True and send the message, the underlying MAPI system automatically tracks the message for you. When you set the DeliveryReceipt property, the MAPI system automatically generates a message to the sender reporting when the recipient receives the message. When you set the ReadReceipt property, the MAPI system automatically generates a message to the sender reporting when the recipient reads the message.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526415(v=exchg.10).aspx

You can also use `ReadReceipt` to know when the message has been read.

Answer (score 0):

The only reliable way I've found to do this is to start polling the item afterwards to see when the changekey arrives, indicating that it got processed.  Details here:

[In Office.js, How do we use the Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync response (overcoming ErrorItemNotFound)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68959703/in-office-js-how-do-we-use-the-office-context-mailbox-item-saveasync-response)

Note that you'll typically get a number of failures over the first few seconds before it finally works - be sure your polling loop knows how to prepare for that.