# In Office.js, How do we use the Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync response (overcoming ErrorItemNotFound)?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, exchangewebservices, outlook-web-addins

The [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messagecompose?view=outlook-js-preview&preserve-view=true#saveAsync_options__callback_) says:

> Note: If your add-in calls saveAsync on an item in compose mode in order to get an item ID to use with EWS or the REST API, be aware that when Outlook is in cached mode, it may **take some time** before the item is actually synced to the server. Until the item is synced, using the itemId will return an error.

As best I can tell, that's the cause of my **ErrorItemNotFound** problems trying to use that ID? (It's a shame Microsoft did not specifically tell us *what* error to expect).

Since my code is invoked asynchronously - how exactly do I wait for the noted "*some time*"?  Do we set a timer to re-try every second or something?  When do we give up??  Is there something else I can do which will give me a call-back to continue when the item sync has completed?  [FYI - even waiting 10 seconds after the save does not work for me]

Be aware that I expect my users may be composing mail with large attachments, so while most no-attachment messages should sync in less than 1 second, folks attaching large pdf/zip/etc files could easily cause more than 1 minute delays here...

Comment: Possibly not a coincidence - I've noticed that if I manually save my email before running my add-in function, the ID's in the saveAsync response work immediately...

Comment: I've also faced with this problem when dealing with a cached mode in Outlook.

Comment: The general advice we give here is to perform all your actions on the client, or on the server to avoid conflicts, item-not-found errors, and to provide an overall better experience for the customer. You can also get an ErrorItemNotFound in other scenarios. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/performance/erroritemnotfound-when-office-add-ins-make-rest-calls. Can you provide us with more information about your scenario and why you need to make an EWS/REST call while the item is being changed locally on the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best what you could do is to start polling for an item appeared on the server side. For example, you may try an ugly solution when you use sub-sequential EWS query with Id you've got from `saveAsync` in the loop and wait for success.

For example, I've noticed the following example how developers try to handle such scenarious:

```
app.makeEwsRequestAsync = function (request, callback, countRepeatIfCrash, callbackIfCrash) {
        try {
            Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(request, function (asyncResult) {
                
                try {
                    
                    if (asyncResult.status !== 'succeeded') {
                        app.showError(asyncResult.error.message);
                        return;
                    } else {
                        var $result = app.getResponseElementByName(asyncResult.value, 'm:ResponseCode');
                        
                        if ($result) {
                            var responseCOde = $result.text();
                            if (responseCOde !== 'NoError') {
                                if (countRepeatIfCrash > 0) {
                                    setTimeout(function () {
                                        app.makeEwsRequestAsync(request, callback, countRepeatIfCrash - 1);
                                    }, 500);
                                } else if (callbackIfCrash) {
                                    setTimeout(function() {
                                        callbackIfCrash();
                                    }, 500);
                                } else if (responseCOde === 'ErrorItemNotFound') {
                                    app.showError('EWS ' + responseCOde, function () {
                                        app.makeEwsRequestAsync(request, callback, 70);
                                    });
                                }
                                else {
                                    app.showError('EWS ' + responseCOde);
                                }
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    callback(asyncResult);

                } catch (e) {
                    app.showError(e);
                }
            });
        } catch (e) {
            app.showError(e);
        }        
    }
```

See [App for Outlook: EWS request failed with item Id returned by item.saveAsync on compose new message](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6a7417d1-8af8-453f-bce0-584b7f79b0c1/app-for-outlook-ews-request-failed-with-item-id-returned-by-itemsaveasync-on-compose-new-message?forum=appsforoffice#f1786d4f-68d1-411f-ae43-c203ff303b5e) for more information.

You may also can try using the simple `GetItem` request:

```
<GetItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
    <ItemShape>
        <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
    </ItemShape>
    <ItemIds><t:ItemId Id="' + itemId + '"/></ItemIds>
</GetItem>
```

The request should return `ChangeKey` if item was created on exchange.

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to use this part of example code: var $result = app.getResponseElementByName(asyncResult.value, 'm:ResponseCode'); but I got an error that "app is not defined"; if I write it as var $result = Office.context.mailbox.getResponseElementByName(asyncResult.value, 'm:ResponseCode'); I got the error "getResponseElementByName is not a function"; Is that function defined in office or defined by you?

Comment: This function is not a part of the JavaScript API for Office (OfficeJS). You can introduce your own functions for handling the XML markup returned by the EWS call.